# Candidates for merging: "Argument vs Parameter"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1788923/538216) is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427653/538216), which is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156767/538216). In general I don't like duplicate chains (I prefer to skip the middle man).

In my opinion the last question linked (the non-dupe) is of the lowest quality. There are good answers in each question. Is this a case for picking one of of them to be canonical and merging them together?

Comment: if you think that the questions should be merged, flag for a mod to merge them.

Answer (score -1):

To add to what Servy just said in a comment above - It will take a mod's permissions to be able to properly consolidate/freeze a thread from further edits if one really should be the "go to" for a particular question. Try flagging the thread for attention.

Answer (score -1):

In all actually I would rather that [this particular one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter) survive alone.

The others have good answers, but they're all already covered in that answer, and very well indeed.  In fact, [one of the answers was so good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427708/1079354), [it had to be stated twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156778/1079354).